# Equation for finding maze solvability

Tags: matrices, functional-equations

I am programming a game where users can edit the state of a maze. The state of each vertical and horizontal wall (present/not present, on/off, 1/0, etc...) is stored in a database and then referenced when users edit the maze. I need an equation for checking that the maze is solvable (i.e. the path from the start to the finish is not blocked) before the edited maze is saved.

The state values of the vertical and horizontal walls are each saved in their own matrix, or if you are familiar with programming, a 2 Dimensional array.

For instance if the vertical walls matrix looks like this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

[image: vertical walls image]

And the horizontal walls matrix looks like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

[image: horizontal walls]

What equation or method could be used to check if a player could get from the green X to the orange X?

[image: maze]

I apologize if my jargon or tags are not accurate. I am coming to this forum from a programming **not** mathematics background. I greatly appreciate any help that could be sent my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a "right hand rule" like this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

You might also find this helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191428/maze-solving-algorithm-in-c

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Links only answer does not address OP's question by the community standard. This should be a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I would be happy to leave these as a comment below the post, but unfortunately I need a 50 reputation or greater.  Hopefully I will soon.